# Escaping a string multiple times

Tags: string, escaping

This probably applies to all languages that have escape characters, but I'm making an example with Python (3.4.2). How would you escape this:
***Warning: Do not use this code ever, this is just an example***

```
#unescaped for examples sake, and using solely " instead of '
eval("eval("print("Hi")")")
```

This won't work:

```
>>> eval("eval(\"print(\"Hi\")\")")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    eval("eval(\"print(\"Hi\")\")")
  File "<string>", line 1
    eval("print("Hi")")
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This also won't work:

```
>>> eval("eval(\"print(\\"Hi\\")\")")
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So how would you escape it?

Answer (score 1):

Escape with three backslashes (`\\\`)

```
eval("eval(\"print(\\\"Hi\\\")\")")
```

Explanation:
In `eval("eval(\"print(\\\"Hi\\\")\")")`, the string being passed is:

```
"eval(\"print(\\\"Hi\\\")\")"
```

When the string is evaluated, all the escape characters are removed. This turns `"\\"` into `\` and `"\""` into `"`. So, you end up with:

```
eval("print(\"Hi\")").
```

(This evaluates `"print(\"Hi\")"`, which is just `print("Hi")`.)

Note this:

```
>>> len("\\") # Escaped letters are on character
1
>>> len("\n")
1
>>> len("nn")
2
>>> "\'" == "'" == '\'' # Various forms of escaped '
True
>>> "\n" == """
""" # Multiline string with a newline
True
>>> "\q" == "q" # q is not escapeable
False
>>> "\q"
'\\q'
>>> len("\q")
2
```